# How to create nice-to-use type-checked aliases for primitive types in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, types, typedef

I'm writing code where I'm creating multiple aliases for primitive types, e.g. *Address* and *Id* being *int*s.

I want to avoid using Addresses and Ids together, e.g. in arithmetic operations.

Thus I would like to have type-checking on these aliases, so that the following result can be obtained:

```
typedef int A;
typedef int B;

A f(A a) { return a+a; };

int main()
{
  A a = 5;
  B b = 5;
  f(a);     // I would like this to work...
  f(b);     // and this not to compile.
}
```

Now this does not work, but I know I can use a wrapper struct/class with just one member:

```
class A { public: int x; A(int xx) { x = xx; }};
class B { public: int x; B(int xx) { x = xx; }};

A f(A a) { return A(a.x+a.x); }; // this is ugly and I'd want to be able to use: return a+a

int main()
{
  A a = 5;
  B b = 5;
  f(a);     // This will work...
  f(b);     // This won't compile...
}
```

**My question is** - what's the best way I can get code working like the 2nd snippet, but without having to explicitly getting *x* all the time and construct new objects (as noted in the line with the "this is ugly" comment)?

I guess I can overload all relevant operators for all my 'aliases' but that's a lot of work and I'm hoping there's a faster/nicer solution.

Thanks.

PS To make this a concrete SO question, not a discussion: I'm just asking for a different way of achieving the result I want, than overloading everything. Thank you.

Comment: `// this is ugly and I'd want to be able to use: return a+a` So, why not overload `operator int()`? [Example](https://ideone.com/VKA0DO).

Comment: So is it OK to add two IDs? Should the result be an ID again? What about multiplication, would  you want to get ID squared?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34287842/c-strongly-typed-using-and-typedef et al.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius - Thanks so much. I was not aware you could do something like that. I suppose that will work for any primitive type?

Comment: @n.m. Oh yeah, that's a valid point, Algirdas's solution makes no restrictions on nonsensical operations. I guess I will just overload the selected operators by hand. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the "best" way but one thing you can do is create **one** type that overloads all the relevant operators and takes an integral template parameter so you can differentiate your types with a number:

```
template<std::size_t ID>
class strongly_typed_int
{
public:
    explicit strongly_typed_int(int i = 0): i(i) {}

    // ...

    strongly_typed_int operator+(strongly_typed_int i) { /*...*/ }
    // etc...

private:
    int i;
};

using security_id = strongly_typed_int<0>;
using access_code = strongly_typed_int<1>;
// etc...
```