# Typedef to enforce property on type

Tags: c++, types, type-conversion

I want to create my own type that asserts some property at runtime, but otherwise behaves exactly as another type.

To get a better idea of what I mean, pretend for a moment unsigned integer types do not exist and I want to create my own type to represent them based on `int`.

I can do something like the following:

```cpp
struct uint {
    int val;
    uint(int v) : val (v) {
         assert(v >= 0);
    }
```

But then I can't use my `uint` struct as a drop in replacement for `int` because I now have to call `uint.val` to access the value. I would like `uint` to behave exactly as an `int` but with the added runtime check during construction that the value is larger than zero.

Go has type embedding via

```golang
type myint {
    int
}
func New(int v) myint {
    // Check v > 0
}
```

and Rust has type aliasing

```rust
type myint = int;
impl myint {
    fn New(int v) -> myint {
        // check that v > 0
    }
}
```

Is it possible to achieve something like this in modern C++?

Comment: Lookup *strong typedefs*, they're a concept close to what you're trying to do and many of the implementation issues are the same. The answer is "not quite, but close enough".

Comment: You could give `uint` an `operator int`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34287842/c-strongly-typed-using-and-typedef

Comment: @stark interesting. Could be relevant. However, OP seems not so much interested in avoiding mixing types, but more in type validation - invariant enforcement