# C++ typed variables using struct

Tags: c++, types

In C++ I want to create a typed variable that won't accidentally be used or converted to some other type.  What I've come up with is:

```
struct  DId {
    uint32_t    v;  
    DId (uint32_t i = 0)    
    {   
        v   =   i;  
    }
};

struct  TId {   
    uint32_t    v;  
    TId (uint32_t i = 0)    
    {   
        v   =   i;  
    }
};
```

This seems to work, though sometimes I need to directly access the value, but are there any other methods I really should define?  Does it use any extra resources at run time?  (I could use preprocesser commands to switch it out with a "using TId = uint32_t" if not in debug mode, though that would mean extra work whenever I need to directly access the value.)

Or is there some better approach that I just haven't noticed?

Comment: Please explain better what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Sounds like you want a [scoped enumeration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Scoped_enumerations), though these don't really work well for arbitrary values, only for avoiding implicit conversion to other types.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts why do you think the post is about *implicit* casts?

Comment: Google "strong types c++"

Comment: using empty struct as a tag.
`
template <typename T>
struct  Id {   
    uint32_t    v;  
    TId (uint32_t i = 0)    
    {   
        v   =   i;  
    }
};

struct TT{};
Id<TT> id(1);
`
like this?

Comment: What's the difference between `DId` and `TId`?

Comment: https://www.fluentcpp.com/2016/12/08/strong-types-for-strong-interfaces/

Comment: You are looking for "strong typedef". Boost has it, your solution is Ok too. Don't bother with doing something else in release mode, there is no overhead.

Comment: probably a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34287842/strongly-typed-using-and-typedef can someone take a look?

Comment: The constructor is unnecessary

Comment: The code to go along with the article from @doug https://github.com/joboccara/NamedType

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may make the structure templated so that it can be used at multiple places and define a typecast operator.

```
template<typename T>
struct Id {
  T v;  
  Id (T i = T{}) { v = i; }. // Ideally not required
  operator T () { return v; } // optional to allow conversion to T
};

using DId = Id<uint32_t>;
```

Your code as it is also fine. Above way is for better utilization and avoid repetition.