# How to find index to a tuple element of type T at compile time?

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, c++17

I want to find the index to a tuple element of type T.
I want to do this at a compile time.
How to do that?
Each type will be used inside the tuple only once, so the types will be unique.

Here's what I have so far:

```
using Tuple_Type = std::tuple
<
    CoolType,
    SomethingElse,
    Boing,
    BingBang
>;

Tuple_Type  m_pool_of_data;


template <typename T>
inline T& Get()
{
    return std::get<T>(m_pool_of_data);     // This one works great
}

template <typename T>
inline int GetIndexOfType()
{
    return ??????;    // How to make this work?
}


Boing b = Get<Boing>();     // Gets the element of type Boing from the tuple
int index_of_type = GetIndexOfType<Boing>();    // Should return 2
```

How to make the **int GetIndexOfType()** work?

I'm using C++17.

EXTRA INFORMATION:

std::get correctly distinguishes types which have been made by

```
using Boing = int;
using BingBang = int;
```

But std::is_same_v seems to think those two are the same type. So that is a problem if I want to resolve the issue using std::is_same_v.

---

SOLUTION:

Here is what I came up with, based on the ideas and feedback given in this thread. Seems to work as intended.

```
template <typename T, int I>
static constexpr int GetTypeIndexFromTuple()
{
    constexpr int tuple_element_count = std::tuple_size<Tuple_Type>();

    // No data type found?
    if constexpr (I >= tuple_element_count)
    {
        return -1;
    } else {
        // Data type found?
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::tuple_element_t<I, Tuple_Type>, T>)
            return I;
        else
            return GetTypeIndexFromTuple<T, I + 1>();   // Test the next tuple element
    }
}


template <typename T>
inline int GetTypeIndex()
{
    int index = GetTypeIndexFromTuple<T, 0>();

    assert(index != -1);

    return index;
}
```

That seems to work.

I also made all my data types to be wrapped inside a struct, if they were not structs or classes originally. That solves the clashing same data types.

This system is being used inside a class, as the class I'm developing is a specialized container.

Comment: I would say a combination of `std::index_sequence`, `std::tuple_element`, `std::same_as_v`, and a fold expression. That should do the trick...

Comment: What version of C++ is available to you?

Comment: I'm using C++17.

Comment: "_std::get correctly distinguishes types which have been made by_": No, these are aliases for the exact same type and so there is no possible way to distinguish them. `std::get<int>` will fail to compile if the variant contains `int` twice.

Comment: Demo of failing to compile: https://godbolt.org/z/x51zvWqYr

Comment: Damn. You're right. My observations were wrong. So there's an extra issue in my code then, which I need to fix. Maybe I'll fix it by wrapping the data inside a struct which goes to the tuple, unless there is some better way.

Comment: Most of the time, you don't need this because tuples can be accessed by index and also by type. https://godbolt.org/z/o88jTxP5s . In your case `std::get<Boing>(tup)`.

Answer (score 1):

An answer using c++20 templated lambda:

```
template <typename Tuple, typename T>
constexpr std::size_t GetIndexOfType()
{
    return []<typename... Ts>(std::type_identity<std::tuple<Ts...>> t){
        std::size_t index = 0;
        (void)((++index, std::is_same_v<Ts, T>) || ...);
        return index - 1;
    }(std::type_identity<Tuple>{});
}
```

The fold expression is a convoluted way to say "while the type is not the same, increment the index".

Although the more canonical way is to use a `std::index_sequence` as suggested in the comments.

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/5a4P5Phfa

It can be easily adapated to C++17 by writing your own `type_identity` and turning the lambda to a free function.

```
template <typename T>
struct type_identity{
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr std::size_t GetIndexOfTypeHelper(type_identity<std::tuple<Ts...>>){
    std::size_t index = 0;
    (void)((++index, std::is_same_v<Ts, T>) || ...);
    return index - 1;    
}

template <typename Tuple, typename T>
constexpr std::size_t GetIndexOfType()
{
    return GetIndexOfTypeHelper<T>(type_identity<Tuple_Type>{});
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/Yhrrxv5dq

Comment: std::get<T> correctly distinguishes types which have been made by "using Boing = int;   using BingBang = int;" But std::is_same_v<T> seems to think those two are the same type. So that is a problem.

Comment: No, after `using Boing=int` and `using BingBong=int`, `Boing` and `BingBong` are just the  same type in all aspects. If you believe otherwise, please provide some code that shows `std::get<T>` "works".

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, note that `GetIndexOfType` really shouldn't be a function since you're not working with any objects, you're just doing metaprogramming with types. In that context, class templates are often more elegant:

```cpp
// helper template finds index of a type in a pack
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct index_of_type {
    static inline constexpr int value = [] {
        int i = 0;
        bool found = ((++i, std::is_same_v<T, Ts>) || ...);
        return found ? i - 1 : -1;
    }();
};
```

```cpp
// helper template to find the index of a type in a tuple-like type
template <typename T, typename Tuple, typename = void>
struct index_of_tuple_type_impl;

template <typename T, typename Tuple>
struct index_of_tuple_type_impl<T, Tuple, std::void_t<decltype(std::tuple_size_v<Tuple>)>> {
    template <std::size_t... Is>
    static constexpr auto get(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        return index_of_type<T, std::tuple_element_t<Is, Tuple>...>::value;
    }
    static inline constexpr auto value = get(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<Tuple>>{});
};
```

```cpp
// clean interface
template <typename T, typename Tuple>
struct index_of_tuple_type : index_of_tuple_type_impl<T, Tuple> {};

template <typename T, typename Tuple>
inline constexpr int index_of_tuple_type_v = index_of_tuple_type<T, Tuple>::value;
```

#### Tests

```cpp
static_assert(index_of_tuple_type_v<int, std::tuple<float, double, int>> == 2);
static_assert(index_of_tuple_type_v<long, std::tuple<float, double, int>> == -1);
static_assert(index_of_tuple_type_v<int, std::array<int, 3>> == 0);
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/oqfce9jM5)*

#### Further Notes

> But `std::is_same_v` seems to think those two are the same type. So that is a problem if I want to resolve the issue using `std::is_same_v`.

That's not something that you can solve; it's a fundamental issue with C++. Aliases are weak, i.e. `typedef` and `using` don't create a distinct type. `std::is_same_v<int, alias_for_int>` is always going to be true, no matter what you do.

See also [Strongly typed using and typedef](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34287842/5740428) for workarounds.

Comment: I figured out a way to do it, based on the feedback in this thread. I wrote the solution in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a higher tech solution (I found the compile time stuff that `std` provides a little bit lacking), you can use a `mpl::vector` instead of a `std::tuple` (they mean the same thing syntactically), and then write a more idiomatic compile time solution like the following:

```
#include <boost/mpl/fold.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/plus.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/int.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/at.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/placeholders.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/equal_to.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>

namespace mpl = boost::mpl;

template<class Sequence, class Target>
struct getTargetIndex
{
    template<class _CurrIndex, class _FoundIndex>
    struct fold_state
    {
        using CurrIndex = _CurrIndex;
        using FoundIndex = _FoundIndex;
    };
    template<class PriorState, class X>
    struct apply_fold
    {
        using type = fold_state<
                mpl::plus<
                    typename PriorState::CurrIndex,
                    mpl::int_<1>
                >,
                typename mpl::if_<
                    typename boost::is_same<
                        Target,
                        typename mpl::at<Sequence, typename PriorState::CurrIndex>::type
                    >::type,
                    typename PriorState::CurrIndex,
                    typename PriorState::FoundIndex
                >::type
            >;
    };
    using type = mpl::fold<
        Sequence,
        fold_state<mpl::int_<0>,mpl::int_<-1>>,
        apply_fold<mpl::_,mpl::_>
    >::type::FoundIndex;
};


struct tests
{
    using tup = mpl::vector<int, bool, int*>;
    static_assert(mpl::equal_to<
                getTargetIndex<tup, int>::type,
                mpl::int_<0>
            >::value);
    static_assert(mpl::equal_to<
                getTargetIndex<tup, bool>::type,
                mpl::int_<1>
            >::value);
    static_assert(mpl::equal_to<
                getTargetIndex<tup, int*>::type,
                mpl::int_<2>
            >::value);
    static_assert(mpl::equal_to<
                getTargetIndex<tup, void*>::type,
                mpl::int_<-1>
            >::value);
};
```